# Reading and displaying an image using C++

Tags: c++, image

I'm actually new to this, and just want to ask about how can we `read` and `display` a digital image using C++?

Thanks.

Comment: C++ as a language does not specify anything about graphics. Which graphical environment are you targeting?

Comment: You should find a C++ library to do this. Search for graphical libraries for C++. (Of course you can also write the code from scratch. But that will take you AGES, especially if you are inexperienced.)

Answer (score 1):

There are very many ways to do it... depending on which framework you use. in Qt, ehich is my favourite, you have the `QImage` class, responsible for such things.

Answer (score 1):

Off course by using a library. It all depends on what you are allowed to use.

If you can use Qt, then use QImage.
If you can use opengl, then load image data into a texture and render the texture.
etc

I am sure there are at least 10 other methods how to do it